# Aligning arrows above equations

Tags: math-mode, alignat

I am really frustrated with the simple task of aligning arrows on top of an equation. The final result should look like this:

[image]

So far I have this:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\Rightarrow \Rightarrow &\Rightarrow &\Rightarrow \\
&^{60}_{27} \text{Co} \longrightarrow ~ ^{60}_{28}\text{Ni}^* + \quad  &e^- + \quad &\overline{\nu}_e\\
& &\longleftarrow &\longrightarrow
\end{alignat*}
```

But the second and the thrid arrows are both above the neutrino.
As might show, I am a beginner in Latex...

Comment: Welcome! Where should the first two arrows be placed?

Comment: Please take a look at these two links: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and a short introduction to [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code that should allow for easier input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\isotope}{O{}mo}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
      {{\mathstrut}#1\mathrm{#2}}}
      {\EvalOptions{#3}{{\mathstrut}#1\mathrm{#2}}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\particle}{mo}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\mathstrut#1}
      {\EvalOptions{#2}{\mathstrut#1}}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\electron}{}{%
  \particle{e^{-}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\neutrino}{}{%
  \particle{\bar{\nu}_{e}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\EvalOptions}{mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { lovemedo/particles } { #1 }
  \overset{\l_lovemedo_particles_above_tl}
   {
    \underset{\l_lovemedo_particles_below_tl}{\vphantom{\Big|}#2}
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\keys_define:nn { lovemedo/particles }
 {
  above .tl_set:N = \l_lovemedo_particles_above_tl,
  below .tl_set:N = \l_lovemedo_particles_below_tl,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\isotope[^{60}_{27}]{Co}[above={\Rightarrow}{\Rightarrow}]
\longrightarrow
\isotope[^{60}_{28}]{Ni}
+
\electron[above=\Rightarrow,below=\leftarrow]
+
\neutrino[above=\Rightarrow,below=\rightarrow]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to increase the space around the reaction arrow and the `+` signs, you can add

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\increasespace}{}{%
  \thickmuskip=\muexpr\thickmuskip*3\relax
  \medmuskip=\muexpr\medmuskip*3\relax
}
```

at the beginning and then input the display as

```
\[
\increasespace
\isotope[^{60}_{27}]{Co}[above={\Rightarrow}{\Rightarrow}]
\longrightarrow
\isotope[^{60}_{28}]{Ni}
+
\electron[above=\Rightarrow,below=\leftarrow]
+
\neutrino[above=\Rightarrow,below=\rightarrow]
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to see, that I apparently chose the correct way of typesetting this (since you used a similar one) :) Just one question: Why the `\Big|` instead of `\mathstrut`?

Comment: @Skillmon `\mathstrut` doesn't ensure alignment between the arrows.

Comment: It does if inserted (almost) everywhere, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The following doesn't look too bad:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \overset{\Rightarrow\Rightarrow\mathstrut}{^{60\mathstrut}_{27} \text{Co}}
  \longrightarrow
  {}^{60\mathstrut}_{28}\text{Ni}^*
  + \underset{\longleftarrow}
    {\overset{\Rightarrow\mathstrut}{e^{\mathstrut-}_{\mathstrut}}}
  + \underset{\longrightarrow}
    {\overset{\Rightarrow\mathstrut}{\overline{\nu}^{\mathstrut}_{e\mathstrut}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{array}{*7c}
    \Rightarrow \Rightarrow& & & &\Rightarrow & &\Rightarrow \\
    ^{60}_{27} \text{Co} &\longrightarrow & ^{60}_{28}\text{Ni}^* &+& e^- &+& \overline{\nu}_e\\
    & & & &\longleftarrow & &\longrightarrow
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]